# win32oleruntimeError: (in ole method 'text':)

Tags: ruby, excel, ui-automation

The error occurs when I try and access the text property:

```
#Here is where my error occurs
$password=wrksheet.cells(rows,"B") ['text']
```

Full example in context:

```
#require "C:\Ruby193\lib\ruby\gems\1.9.1\gems\rack-1.4.0\lib\rack\logger.rb"
require "watir"
require "watir-webdriver"
require "test/unit"
require "win32ole"

class TC_Login < Test::Unit::TestCase

    browser = Watir::Browser.new :ff
    browser.goto "gaana.com"
    #browser.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10
    browser.a(:class,"closeBtn").wait_until_present
    browser.a(:class,"closeBtn").click

    def test_login

        #Define the excel file
        excel= WIN32OLE::new("excel.Application")
        wrkbook=excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\data\\test.xls")
        wrksheet = wrkbook.worksheets(1)
        wrksheet.select     

        #read the data from excel file
        rows = 2
            while    rows <= 9
                    #Here is where my error occurs
                    $password=wrksheet.cells(rows,"B") ['text']
                    puts $field
                    $username=wrksheet.cells(rows,"A") ['text']
                    $fullname=wrksheet.cells(rows,"C") ['text']

                    browser.a(:id,"joinus").click
                    browser.text_field(:id,"fullname").set($fullname)
                    browser.text_field(:id,"email").set($username)
                    browser.text_field(:id,"Password").set($password)
                    browser.a(:id, "save" ).click

                    rows=rows+1
            end
    end
end
```

Comment: Two things: 1) What is the error you are getting (please provide the full stacktrace)? 2) It's not clear what you mean by 'text' method. I don't see any text method being used. I see a 'text' *key* being used with your worksheet.cells. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Also, there is no need to require both watir and watir-webdriver.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, but you still need to provide the full text of the error that is being thrown.

Answer (score 1):

To get the text of an excel cell, the method is `value` or `text` (both appear to work, though I did not check if there were any technical differences).

The script should work if you change the line (and the others similar to it) to:

```
$password = wrksheet.cells(rows,"B").text
```

or

```
$password = wrksheet.cells(rows,"B").value
```

Comment: i have been running these script from command prompt(windows 7.0),so do not have option to copy complete errors. if you can suggest a IDE to run these scripts + implementing ".text" in place of "['text']" resolved the error related with text, but now i m getting an error "undefined local variable or method 'browser'" in test_login.

Comment: @johnplayer, it would help if you could keep one question per question. But to answer, you can copy from command prompt (right click > select all; press enter). I use SciTE for writing scripts, but is not really an IDE. For your new error, you probably need to put the code that opens the browser in a `setup` method, as well as use instance variables instead of local variables.

Comment: now i m trying to use global variables but getting following error:C:\rubygems\test>ruby GaanaLogin.rb
Run options:

# Running tests:


E

Finished tests in 0.372000s, 2.6882 tests/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

  1) Error:
test_login(TC_Login):
NoMethodError: undefined method `a' for nil:NilClass
    GaanaLogin.rb:35:in `test_login'

1 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips

C:\rubygems\test>

Comment: Ok resolved the error by putting @@ in the variable,any other more feasible approach to resolve this keeping in mind that i m working for a framework.